# "Content URL must not be nil" error when playing video

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am playing video from a local file in my application and it works properly, but then suddenly playing the video crashes the application with this error:

> 2010-03-10 11:34:20.235
>   SanjeevKapoor[1560:20b] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'Content URL must not be nil.'

This is the code where I get the crash:

```
-(void)initAndPlayMovie:(NSURL *)movieURL
{
   // Initialize a movie player object with the specified URL
   MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]  initWithContentURL:movieURL];  // This line causes the crash
   if (movieURL)
   {
      . . .
   }
}
```

Comment: Read the error. The hint is very clear. You need to pass in a valid NSURL instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are handing the movieURL to the `MPMoviePlayerController` before checking if it's nil. You have to do it after the check.